# Integrating js file to Anuglar

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, charts

I would integrate this library [on github](https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts) in my Angular project that adds a new option to my chartJS graph

```
@ViewChild('myChart') myChart: ElementRef;
myChartBis: Chart;
....
....

const ctx = this.myChart.nativeElement.getContext('2d');
this.myChartBis = new Chart(ctx, {
  type: 'bar',
  data: {
    labels: this.labels,
    datasets: [{
      label: 'test',
      showLine: true,
      lineTension: 0,
      data: this.data,
      fill: false,
      pointBorderColor: '#cd0037',
      pointBackgroundColor: '#ffffff',
      borderColor: [
        '#747678',
      ],
      borderWidth: 0
    }
    ],
  },
  options: {
    showLines: true,
    legend: {
      display: false,
    },
    responsive: true,
    maintainAspectRatio: true,
    cornerRadius: 20,
    ...
  }
});
```

Here's the steps I made

1. I have added the js file in `angular.json` under `build`

   `scripts": [
      "src/assets/scripts/Chart.roundedBarCharts.js"
     ]`
2. add `cornerRadius: 20` to graph options
3. restart app.

I get an error that it does not recognize the new option :

```
Type '{ showLines: true; legend: { display: false; }; responsive: true; maintainAspectRatio: true; corn...' is not assignable to type 'ChartOptions'.
```

I gess that I have not well imported js file into Angular app

Comment: You're meaning the `angular.json` instead of  `package.json`, right?

Comment: `declare var Chart: any` try to declare a variable in your component where you want to use the chart

Answer (score 0):

Your options must follow the `ChartOptions` interface (refer to https://github.com/DefinitelyTyped/DefinitelyTyped/blob/master/types/chart.js/index.d.ts)

```
    interface ChartOptions {
        responsive?: boolean;
        responsiveAnimationDuration?: number;
        aspectRatio?: number;
        maintainAspectRatio?: boolean;
        events?: string[];
        legendCallback?(chart: Chart): string;
        onHover?(this: Chart, event: MouseEvent, activeElements: Array<{}>): any;
        onClick?(event?: MouseEvent, activeElements?: Array<{}>): any;
        onResize?(this: Chart, newSize: ChartSize): void;
        title?: ChartTitleOptions;
        legend?: ChartLegendOptions;
        tooltips?: ChartTooltipOptions;
        hover?: ChartHoverOptions;
        animation?: ChartAnimationOptions;
        elements?: ChartElementsOptions;
        layout?: ChartLayoutOptions;
        scales?: ChartScales;
        showLines?: boolean;
        spanGaps?: boolean;
        cutoutPercentage?: number;
        circumference?: number;
        rotation?: number;
        devicePixelRatio?: number;
        plugins?: ChartPluginsOptions;
    }
```

I can't see the whole object, but at least `conrnerRadius` is not a property of ChartOptions

Comment: Look at the github repo, it's an addition https://github.com/jedtrow/Chart.js-Rounded-Bar-Charts
So I'm wondering how to integrate it